# If $+\infty\leq\mu(A)$ then $\mu(A)=+\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, real-numbers, infinity

Let $(X,\mathbb{X},\mu)$ be a positive measure space. Let $A$ belong to $\mathbb{X}$. If $+\infty\leq\mu(A)$ then $\mu(A)=+\infty$. Is this statement correct?

My answer is yes. I believe this is very intuitive. However, I'm not entirely convinced of the formality. Indeed, $+\infty\leq\mu(A)$ and $\mu(A)\leq +\infty$ then $\mu(A)=+\infty$. In this example, I would be treating infinity as a real number and applying the property:
$a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ then $a=b$. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: Does the book you are reading have a section on the axioms defining the extended real numbers? That should answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This has very little to do with measure theory – it's about the axiomatic properties of the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line) $\overline{\mathbb R}$ (also denoted as $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$). Since $+\infty$ is the greatest extended real number, if $x\in\overline{\mathbb R}$ and $x\ge+\infty$, then $x=+\infty$. Indeed, the axioms of the extended reals assert, among other things, that $\le$ is a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on $\overline{\mathbb R}$, and so $\le$ has the antisymmetric property.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, I would be surprised if the OP has any knowledge about extended real numbers.

Comment: @VincentBatens: If that is true, then I would suggest that the OP follows the links in my answer and tries to learn about the extended real numbers. Measure theory is very often formulated in terms of the extended real numbers, and so I think if you do not have at least some familiarity with them, then you won't get far.

Comment: Fair, I thought it was something not necessarily connected to measure theory, my bad.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help in understanding this.

Comment: @JoseEsparrago: No problem. I'm glad I could help. Let me know if you have any questions.